# Can I 'highlight' certain options in UIpickerview?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I would like some of the options in my upickerview to have, say, blue, instead of white as a background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:` method in your delegate. Just create the views as you want them and return them in this method.